# Wrap scientific names of an x-axis variable in two lines

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis-labels

I am trying to make a bar chart, I have the following data:

```
df2 <- data.frame(trat = c("Trichoderma harzianum","Trichoderma virens","Trichoderma asperellum","Chemical control","Control"),
                plant_h = c(39.32, 41.22, 37.29, 40.10, 35.62))
```

The variable that I am trying to graph is plant height:

```
ggplot(df2, aes(trat, plant_h, fill=trat)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge", width = 0.50)+
  scale_x_discrete(labels = scales::label_wrap(10))
```

But I need to show only the scientific names in italic

Comment: Read about ggtext for all custom texts in ggplots: https://wilkelab.org/ggtext/